# javascript program without using math. pow, find power of any number using for loop

Tags: javascript

I need to know the code built in for  the syntax math.pow(x,y). Actually I used the syntax to find exponent of any number... e.g. 
var e = Math.pow(-3, 3); yields -27 but couldn't find out the program behind this... Help me please

Comment: http://www.mathsisfun.com/definitions/power.html

Comment: does the number need to be integer or it can be float as well?

Answer (score 6):

If you know what power means..

> multiplying the number x n times where x is base and n is exponent.

So you just have to repeat the same thing over and over - and that's why loops are for:

```
var sum = 1; //note that it's not zero!
for (int i=0;i<n;i++) { //loops n times
  sum = sum * x; //on each loop multiplies sum by base number
}
```

Comment: Can you explain why `sum` does not start out as 0 here?

Comment: @HappyHands31 because you don't add things up but multiply them to each other. If you start with 0 and multiply x every time, it will stay 0.
Try it with real numbers as example and u'll understand!

Comment: this doesnt work if n is negative

Answer (score 3):

Did you mean alternative for Math.pow? Here is one way with simple loop.

```
function pow(base,power) {
  var p = 1;
  for (var i=0; i<power; i++) {
    p *= base;
  }
  return p;
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer (for simple cases where exponents are guaranteed to be positive integers). Recursion is worse, for the reason stated in the comment on Asher. M. O's answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use recursion to solve this kind of challenge. Beware that recursion has the disadvantage of increasing space complexity as compared to a `for-loop`.

```
    function pow(base, power) {
      if (power === 1) return base * power
      return base * pow(base, power - 1)
    }
```

Comment: A regular `for-loop` with a sumtotal is recommended, because it will iteratively sum the results into the same sumtotal memory location. Whereas recursion will save stack frames for every function call (to be able to backtrace and sum up the results) so it will use up a lot more memory, and will probably also be slightly slower, because of the function calls.

Answer (score 0):

This is a better way to calculate power of a number with recursion:

```
function power(base, exp) {
    if(exp === 0){
        return 1;
    }
    return base * power(base, exp - 1);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```js
function pow(n, e) {
  let num = n;
  for (let i = 1; i < e; i++) {
    num *= n;
  }
  return num;
}
console.log(pow(-3, 3));
```

It will give you the required result.